# swig/python array of structure in a union

Tags: python, arrays, swig

I am a beginner in the world of swig/python and was trying to access an array of C-structure in python, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'bar' object does not support indexing

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

foo.h:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
typedef struct bar {
   uint8_t val;
}bar;

typedef struct foo {
   union {
      bar b[2];
   } u;
}foo;

int fill_foo(foo *);
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

int
fill_foo(foo *var)
{
   var->u.b[0].val = 10;
   var->u.b[1].val = 20;
   return 0;
}
```

foo_test.i:

```
%module foo_test
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"
```

foo.py:

```
import foo_test
f = foo_test.foo()
foo_test.fill_foo(f)
print f.u.b[0]
```

I have read a few other posts about c-arrays and swig, but its not clear to me how     can i can solve this particular case. Would be glad if someone can help me out.

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn18 It's a pointer, you can't use normal indexing of it. If the array is only 2 big, why are you using an array at all?

Comment: @Natecat array of 2 elements is only an example/simplification. My actual code uses a larger array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some poking around I figured out that I need to extend struct bar to fix the issue. I was able to get my above sample code working with the following addition to foo_test.i.

```
%extend bar {
   const bar __getitem__(int i) {
      return $self[i];
   }
}
```

The one downside though is that I need to add such an extension for every structure that gets used as array. Still haven't figured out how to solve this generically for all array of structures.